# Erratic StampedLock.unlock(long) behaviour?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, java-8

I'm facing a strange behaviour about [StampedLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html). Here are the main problematic lines of code :

```
StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();
long stamp1 = lock.readLock();
System.out.printf("Read lock count: %d%n", lock.getReadLockCount());
lock.unlock(stamp1 + 2);
System.out.printf("Read lock count: %d%n", lock.getReadLockCount());
```

The strange behaviour is about how unlock "tolerates" wrong read stamp. Does it seem correct to you?

---

For reference here is the full code:

```
public class StampedLockExample {
  static StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();

  static void println(String message, Object... args) {
    System.out.printf(message, args);
    System.out.println();
  }

  static void printReadLockCount() {
    println("Lock count=%d", lock.getReadLockCount());
  }

  static long tryReadLock() {
    long stamp = lock.tryReadLock();
    println("Gets read lock (%d)", stamp);
    printReadLockCount();
    return stamp;
  }

  static long tryWriteLock() {
    long stamp = lock.tryWriteLock();
    println("Gets write lock (%d)", stamp);
    return stamp;
  }

  static long tryConvertToReadLock(long stamp) {
    long newOne = lock.tryConvertToReadLock(stamp);
    println("Gets read lock (%d -> %d)", stamp, newOne);
    printReadLockCount();
    return newOne;
  }

  static void tryUnlock(long stamp) {
    try {
      lock.unlock(stamp);
      println("Unlock (%d) successfully", stamp);
    } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
      println("Unlock (%d) failed", stamp);
    }
    printReadLockCount();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    println("%n--- Gets two read locks ---");
    long stamp1 = tryReadLock();
    long stamp2 = tryReadLock();
    long min = Math.min(stamp1, stamp2);
    long max = Math.max(stamp1, stamp2);

    println("%n--- Tries unlock (-1 / +2 / +4) ---");
    tryUnlock(min - 1);
    tryUnlock(max + 2);
    tryUnlock(max + 4);

    println("%n--- Gets write lock ---");
    long stamp3 = tryWriteLock();

    println("%n--- Tries unlock (-1 / +1) ---");
    tryUnlock(stamp3 - 1);
    tryUnlock(stamp3 + 1);

    println("%n--- Tries write > read conversion ---");
    long stamp4 = tryConvertToReadLock(stamp3);

    println("%n--- Tries unlock last write stamp (-1 / 0 / +1) ---");
    tryUnlock(stamp3 - 1);
    tryUnlock(stamp3);
    tryUnlock(stamp3 + 1);

    println("%n--- Tries unlock (-1 / +1) ---");
    tryUnlock(stamp4 - 1);
    tryUnlock(stamp4 + 1);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
--- Gets two read locks ---
Gets read lock (257)
Lock count=1
Gets read lock (258)
Lock count=2

--- Tries unlock (-1 / +2 / +4) ---
Unlock (256) failed
Lock count=2
Unlock (260) successfully
Lock count=1
Unlock (262) successfully
Lock count=0

--- Gets write lock ---
Gets write lock (384)

--- Tries unlock (-1 / +1) ---
Unlock (383) failed
Lock count=0
Unlock (385) failed
Lock count=0

--- Tries write > read conversion ---
Gets read lock (384 -> 513)
Lock count=1

--- Tries unlock last write stamp (-1 / 0 / +1) ---
Unlock (383) failed
Lock count=1
Unlock (384) failed
Lock count=1
Unlock (385) failed
Lock count=1

--- Tries unlock (-1 / +1) ---
Unlock (512) failed
Lock count=1
Unlock (514) successfully
Lock count=0
```

Comment: Code should be posted in the question.

Comment: Can't because SO refuse to post my q° because code represents too much text

Comment: I have added MCVE but I also would like feedbacks about behaviour over the entire test case (readLock, unlock, writeLock, re-unlock, write2read conversion and finally unlock)

Comment: Looking at the StampedLock source code in OpenJDK I don't see that it stores 'valid' stamps. It only checks stamps to be in valid range. For read locks anything between 257(100000001b) and 383(101111111) is valid until there's more than 127 readers(then overflow mechanism kicks in). http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.java

Comment: Is there some background to your question? How does this even happen in practice?

Comment: @the8472 I'm currently writing a paper about java.util.concurrent.* packages and plays a lot with API. I was wondering about wrong usage of this lock when observed this behaviour.

Comment: If you're doing research you should also look at the implementations, they're quite informative. The source comes in the src.zip with the JDK. You can wire up your IDE to automatically open the source files when inspecting the classes.

Comment: (1) I don't want to take too long time decrypting source code (concurrent API is quite well but some part of implementation are a bit complex to understand it just with a brief look) . The paper is written only as 'benevol', not for 'eat job'. (2) From my experience : what documentation said, what people expect/understand and what implementation does are often quite similar but not exact equivalent. And revealing those differences is my main goal when I wrote technical paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Adding two to the stamp is modifying a portion of it which does not require validation in read-mode locks.

**Long answer:**

The stamp contains two pieces of information:  a state sequence number, and how many readers there are.  The state number is stored in the first 57 bits of the stamp, and the reader count is stored in the last 7 bits.  So when you add 2 to the stamp, you are changing the reader count from 1 to 3, and leaving the state number unchanged.  Since the StampedLock has only been acquired in read mode, just the state number is validated and the reader count is ignored.  This makes sense because read locks should be able to unlock in any order.

For example:  A read stamp is acquired from an existing StampedLock and has a state number of 4 and a reader count of 1.  A second read stamp is acquired from the same StampedLock and has a state number of 4 and a reader count of 2.  Note that the state numbers of the stamps are the same because the StampedLock's state has not changed in between acquisition of the stamps.  The first read stamp is used in an unlock.  The state number of the first stamp (4) matches the state number of the StampedLock (4), so that's fine.  The reader count of the first stamp (1) does not match the reader count of the StampedLock (2), but that doesn't matter, because read locks should be able to unlock in any order.  So the unlock succeeds.

Note that [StampedLocks were designed to be high-performing read/write locks](http://www.ndcmagazine.com/stampedlock/) for internal utilities, not something to withstand malicious coding, so it is operating within its intended boundaries.  I do think the Javadoc of [unlock()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html#unlock-long-) is misleading though.

Comment: +1. Check the code at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.java#StampedLock.unlock%28long%29 

You can see that the unlock method masks out the last few bits in all the comparison operations.

Comment: Since I have posted question I have made more experiences and observed mask usage for marking state in stamps. And only "state" is checked not the raw stamp value.

Answer (score 3):

the key part from the javadocs:

> Stamps use finite representations, and are not cryptographically secure (i.e., a valid stamp may be guessable).

This means you should treat them as opaque values and not try to modify them in any way.

The *may be guessable* essentially is what your -1, +2, +4 arithmetics do. It's not just guessable but easy to do so if you got a good starting point for guessing, such as a previous token.

Additionally, [StampedLock.validate(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html#validate-long-) states:

> Invoking this method with a value not obtained from tryOptimisticRead() or a locking method for this lock has no defined effect or result.

In other words: Any token value not directly obtained from one of the Lock's methods is not only invalid but also entails undefined behavior.